# Why would a pin not go high on an Arduino?

Tags: arduino

I'm using a SparkFun-built Arduino Pro Mini 3.3V / 8MHz. One thing I need it to do is toggle the gate pin on a MOSFET, and that's not working for some reason. Getting in there with a multimeter, I see that the voltage on the pin never goes HIGH. The only thing I have running on there is the following bit of code:

```
void setup()  {
  pinMode(A7, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(A7, HIGH);
}
```

Any thoughts on either configuration or electronics that could be causing this?

The pertinent part of the schematic is:

[image]

Comment: From the schematic, it appears that both A6 and A7 are used in a similar way. Does the A6 pin work if wired to the RUD_EN connection (and vice versa)? Do you have a replacement Arduino Mini to test with, the processor or board connection may be bad?

Comment: No, they're behaving the same way. I did test with another one - no go. It's definitely either a wiring issue or a code issue, not something with the board

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A6 and A7 are Analog Input Only.  This is most likely what your are running into.

The TQFP package of the AtMega328 has 2 more inputs that the DIP package (A6 and A7), but they are analog input only.  1.1.9 in the datasheet.

Comment: *sigh* yes - it's looking that way.

Comment: @kolosy - If you could see fit to add a small I<sup>2</sup>C parallel port expander to your design your could take the two wire port of the MCU and get support for 8 I/O pins at the expense of only two on the MCU. At least the port expander could be used to drive RUD_EN and WINCH_EN and monitor RUD_V and WIN_V.

Comment: I'll look into that, thanks. I think for the time being, I just need to move some things around, still have enough GPIOs.